# filling sunken living room with concrete

Tags: concrete

While I have found a lot of information already about anchoring or dowelling the new concrete floor to the existing slab, I have not found anything what to do with my outside wall, which is at the lower level, with wood framing and drywall. What is recommended here?

Also if I pour a new patio, what do I need to do with my siding which will now have 4" of concrete up against it?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. You've asked two distinct questions here, neither of which provides enough information for us to answer. You'll need to reduce to one and add details.

Comment: Also photos are helpful, and your location in the world

Comment: Ask a **new** question with just your second question in it. [Edit] this question to remove the second question and add details/pictures. Take the [tour]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Both this question and a new one need a _lot_ more detail. Drawings and/or pictures of the areas in question would help _tremendously_. Don't forget, we can't see what you see, so what's obvious to you has to be explained in detail to us. Help us help you by [edit]ing this question to include more details and it'll likely get reopened.

Answer (score 2):

I know of several sunken rooms which were raised to the level of the adjacent levels. All of them were done with wooden joists. It seems to me that filling the sunken room with concrete would not be advisable. I would guess that if would be so much extra weight that the existing slab would sink under the added weight. Then there is is problem you mention about the concrete next to the stud wall.